# Masters Admissions and Academic Dishonesty

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters

The summer before my last year of undergrad I committed academic dishonesty in one of my summer classes. I received a sanction of a course grade of 0 and a notation on my transcript until I graduate, which would be June of 2015. I decided to take a year off in light of my transgressions (I wasn't suspended but felt that if I could do something that heinous I needed to take a step back and reevaluate  everything).

I'm a psych&stats major and I wanted to eventually work in research or some related field as I work as a RA at school and it's something I'm interested in. My overall goal was to find work after graduation and at some point when I have some career direction apply to a Master's program. However, in light of the academic dishonesty I'm not sure how it will affect my application, or if it's something that's redeemable?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: hey, I did read this thread, but I didn't find it particularly helpful for my situation. But, thanks !

Comment: I'd consider it redeemable. This documented incident might well close some doors, but likely not all of them.

Answer (score 1):

> However, in light of the academic dishonesty I'm not sure how it will affect my application, or if it's something that's redeemable?

From a graduate admissions point of view, relatively speaking, having a note on your transcript concerning your academic dishonesty violation is not as bad as being kicked out of undergraduate studies altogether (as noted in this answer [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/15288/is-it-possible-to-do-a-masters-degree-without-obtaining-a-bachelors-degree/15339#15339) to the following question: [Is it possible to do a Master's degree without obtaining a Bachelor's degree?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/15288/is-it-possible-to-do-a-masters-degree-without-obtaining-a-bachelors-degree/)).

So, your school is giving you another chance. It's up to you now to make the most of your remaining time in your undergraduate studies. In my view, here are some things you can do to improve your chances of admission at the graduate level:

- Do *really* well in your remaining coursework.
- Take up a research project (or two or three). You should do this anyway if you are serious about graduate studies.
- Build a professional network, such as professors for your courses or your research project advisor. In addition to helping you become a better student/researcher, these folks will come in handy when it comes time to submit letters of recommendation along with your graduate studies application materials.

You already took some time off from your studies to reflect on your actions, but it bears repeating: **Don't dwell on this indiscretion**. All you can do is move forward and utilize every bit of time you have left in your undergraduate studies to increase the odds in your favor of admission to a graduate program.

---

Edit: OP mentioned that they are an RA, but my 2nd bullet point above is added for future users in a similar situation.

Comment: I agree with the comment that you shouldn't dwell on the past. However, when it comes to be time to apply for graduate study, you should be ready to answer questions about what happened, and why it won't happen again. They might not get asked, but if they are you want to be able to offer well-considered answers.